# Retrieving execution time of Python function with different arguments

Tags: python, plot, time

I have the task to measure how much time it takes to execute a function with different parameters and plot the result. I am using the python standard libraries `time` and there is something strange happening during the first execution.

Here is my [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohDO1.png)

As you see first two values of `nns` are the same, but it takes much longer during the first execution

````
nns = [10, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 20000, 40000]

# measure retrival time for every value above and save it somewhere 
times = []

for k in nns:
    point = random.choice(dataset)[0]
    start_time = time.time()
    ids, distances = index.knnQuery(paris, k=k)
    t = time.time() - start_time
    times.append(t*100) #miliseconds - for convinience

print(times)
# plot the results
plt.plot(nns, times)

plt.show() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `index.knnQuery` is instantiated lazily. Maybe there are components that are just in time compiled, or data is only read into memory when it is first executed.

If you have doubt about your implementation of the testing schema, you should unit test it. E.g. replace index.knnQuery with a sleep function (`from time import sleep; sleep(nns)`)